# make monthly ranges in R

Tags: r

I've this function to generate monthly ranges, it should consider years where february has 28 or 29 days:

```
   starts     ends
1  2017-01-01 2017-01-31
2  2017-02-01 2017-02-28
3  2017-03-01 2017-03-31
```

It works with:

```
make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), Sys.Date())
```

But gives error with:

```
make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))
```

Why?

```
make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))
Error in data.frame(starts, ends) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 38, 36

add_months <-  function(date, n){
  seq(date, by = paste (n, "months"), length = 2)[2]
}

make_date_ranges <- function(start, end){

  starts <- seq(from = start,
                to =  Sys.Date()-1 ,
                by = "1 month")

  ends <- c((seq(from = add_months(start, 1),
                 to = end,
                 by = "1 month" ))-1,
            (Sys.Date()-1))

  data.frame(starts,ends)

}

## useage
make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused why `Sys.Date()` is showing up in the function code... what's the expected output? At a glance it looks like you're after generating monthly intervals encompassing all months from `start` to `end`

Comment: Does @MichaelChirico s answer solve your problem?

Comment: @dario it gives an extra line. `Using my_dates <- make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))` returns also `2020-01-01 2020-01-31` as the last row. When it is not needed. Because, call was with end date: `2019-12-31` May you test it also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** First, define start of month, `som`, and end of month, `eom` functions which take a `Date` class object, date string in standard `Date` format or `yearmon` object and produce a `Date` class object giving the start or end of its year/months.

Using those, create a monthly `Date` series `s` using the start of each month from the month/year of `from` to that of `to`.  Use `pmax` to ensure that the series does not extend before `from` and `pmin` so that it does not extend past `to`.

The input arguments can be strings in standard `Date` format, `Date` class objects or `yearmon` class objects.  In the `yearmon` case it assumes the user wanted the full month for every month.  (The `if` statement can be omitted if you don't need to support `yearmon` inputs.)

```
library(zoo)

som <- function(x) as.Date(as.yearmon(x))
eom <- function(x) as.Date(as.yearmon(x), frac = 1)

date_ranges2 <- function(from, to) {
  if (inherits(to, "yearmon")) to <- eom(to)
  s <- seq(som(from), eom(to), "month")
  data.frame(from = pmax(as.Date(from), s), to = pmin(as.Date(to), eom(s)))
}

date_ranges2("2000-01-10", "2000-06-20")
##         from         to
## 1 2000-01-10 2000-01-31
## 2 2000-02-01 2000-02-29
## 3 2000-03-01 2000-03-31
## 4 2000-04-01 2000-04-30
## 5 2000-05-01 2000-05-31
## 6 2000-06-01 2000-06-20

date_ranges2(as.yearmon("2000-01"), as.yearmon("2000-06"))
##         from         to
## 1 2000-01-01 2000-01-31
## 2 2000-02-01 2000-02-29
## 3 2000-03-01 2000-03-31
## 4 2000-04-01 2000-04-30
## 5 2000-05-01 2000-05-31
## 6 2000-06-01 2000-06-30
```

**2)** This alternative takes the same approach but defines start of month (`som`) and end of month (`eom`) functions without using `yearmon` so that only base R is needed.  It takes character strings in standard `Date` format or `Date` class inputs and gives the same output as (1).

```
som <- function(x) as.Date(cut(as.Date(x), "month")) # start of month
eom <- function(x) som(som(x) + 32) - 1 # end of month

date_ranges3 <- function(from, to) {
  s <- seq(som(from), as.Date(to), "month")
  data.frame(from = pmax(as.Date(from), s), to = pmin(as.Date(to), eom(s)))
}

date_ranges3("2000-01-10", "2000-06-20")
##         from         to
## 1 2000-01-10 2000-01-31
## 2 2000-02-01 2000-02-29
## 3 2000-03-01 2000-03-31
## 4 2000-04-01 2000-04-30
## 5 2000-05-01 2000-05-31
## 6 2000-06-01 2000-06-20

date_ranges3(som("2000-01-10"), eom("2000-06-20"))
##         from         to
## 1 2000-01-01 2000-01-31
## 2 2000-02-01 2000-02-29
## 3 2000-03-01 2000-03-31
## 4 2000-04-01 2000-04-30
## 5 2000-05-01 2000-05-31
## 6 2000-06-01 2000-06-30
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `seq` twice -- you can subtract 1 day from the firsts of each month to get the ends, and generate one too many `starts`, then shift & subset:

```
make_date_ranges = function(start, end) {
  # format(end, "%Y-%m-01") essentially truncates end to 
  #   the first day of end's month; 32 days later is guaranteed to be
  #   in the subsequent month
  starts = seq(from = start, to = as.Date(format(end, '%Y-%m-01')) + 32, by = 'month')
  data.frame(starts = head(starts, -1L), ends = tail(starts - 1, -1L))
}
x = make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))
rbind(head(x), tail(x))
#        starts       ends
# 1  2017-01-01 2017-01-31
# 2  2017-02-01 2017-02-28
# 3  2017-03-01 2017-03-31
# 4  2017-04-01 2017-04-30
# 5  2017-05-01 2017-05-31
# 6  2017-06-01 2017-06-30
# 31 2019-07-01 2019-07-31
# 32 2019-08-01 2019-08-31
# 33 2019-09-01 2019-09-30
# 34 2019-10-01 2019-10-31
# 35 2019-11-01 2019-11-30
# 36 2019-12-01 2019-12-31
```

Comment: Using `my_dates <- make_date_ranges(as.Date("2017-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"))` returns also ` 2020-01-01 2020-01-31` as the last row. When it is not needed

Comment: @MichaelChirico: I could not reproduce the output you show. I also get 37 rows, as mentioned in OPs comment...

Comment: Thanks @dario @OmarGonzales -- I was mistaken about `trunc.Date`. Have edited now.